# On a one-time self-re-defining function pattern

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider the following pattern:

```
function foo /* aka outer_foo */ () {

    // === stage 1 ===
    // declaration and initialization of closure variables

    var ... <CLOSURE_VARS> ...;

    // initialization of CLOSURE_VARS
    // (possibly expensive and/or depending on values known only at run-time)


    // === stage 2 ===
    // one-time redefinition of foo

    foo = function /* inner_foo */ ( arg0, ... ) {
        var results;

        // code computing value of results based on CLOSURE_VARS, arg0, ...

        // foo is never modified here

        return results;
    };


    // === stage 3 ===
    // invocation of inner function and returning of result

    return foo.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

For convenience, I will use the terms *outer_foo* and *inner_foo* to designate, respectively, the outer and inner functions above, even though the code does not use these identifiers.

The body of *outer_foo* comprises three stages (the last two consisting of a single statement each):

1. declaration and initialization of some closure variables;
2. redefinition of the identifier `foo`;
3. passing to *inner_foo* the arguments originally passed to *outer_foo*, and returning the result.

The body of *outer_foo* will be executed at most once, namely, the first time that "the function named `foo`" is called, if it ever happens.  Henceforth, the body of *outer_foo* will be unreachable, and all subsequent calls to "the function named `foo`" will result in the execution of *inner_foo*.

In general, one may envision some variations on this pattern <sup>1</sup>, but the essential constraints on the basic scheme I'm talking about here are:

1. `foo` is re-defined exactly once during the execution of `outer_foo`<sup>2</sup>;
2. `foo` is never re-defined during the execution of `inner_foo`.

(If these essential constraints are violated, all bets are off; such a case is outside the scope of this question.)

---

I am already aware of at least one downside of this scheme: some practitioners consider self-redefining functions confusing, detrimental to code readability, and/or inherently in poor taste, even when the re-definition happens only once in a completely deterministic manner, as is the case in the scheme above.

My question is:

> Does this scheme have any **additional** downsides, and if so, what are they?
>
> I'm particularly interested in those downsides that are specific to JavaScript.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For example,</sup>

```
function foo /* aka outer_foo */ () {
    var inner_foo, ... <CLOSURE_VARS> ...;

    if ( some_deterministic_test() ) {
        inner_foo = function ( arg0, ... ) {
            // etc.
        }
    }
    else {
        inner_foo = function ( arg0, ... ) {
            // etc.
        }
    }


    foo = inner_foo;

    return foo.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

<sup>In this variant, the function ultimately assigned to `foo` depends on some test performed at run-time.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Here it's tempting to stipulate that `foo` not only must be re-defined exactly once within *outer_foo*, but that this be done "deterministically".  Of course, any deviation from "determinism" (however one chooses to define it) in final setting of `foo` can only increase the complexity of the code's run-time behavior.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to make this stipulation precise without descending into a maze of lawyerly minutiae.  The best I could do would be to add the weasely—and borderline incoherent—phrase "the more deterministic the better", and hope that readers get my point.  The only utility of this additional stipulation, however, would be to rule out perverse, but wholly unrealistic, scenarios (e.g. having the final value of `foo` depend on the outcome of a random process), so I left it out.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two additional points you should be aware of:

- **performance**. Compilers are like the people you mentioned. Some of them will get confused by this pattern, and they might not be able to optimise it like they would if a different pattern was used. This might or might not be a concern, but you should make sure to test it.
- **broken contracts**. You say you expect *outer_foo* to be executed at most once. This might not be the case! Someone might pass it around and put a reference to it somewhere, so that it does not become unreachable when being called. Sure, that's unlikely, but depending on your requirements you might want to guard against it.
  After all, it's kind of a broken design, as a mere *alias* (`var f = foo; f()`) should never alter functionality. Make sure all consumers/users know what you are doing so they don't trip over it.